# OpenGL VAO initialization in Haskell

Tags: haskell, opengl, functional-programming

I'm writing a kind of framework in Haskell. For now I'm just trying to draw a line on the screen with OpenGL. The idea is that the user just writes something like this:

```
module BBApp
( app
) where

import BB.Main

line :: Polyline
line = newPolyline

points :: [Point]
points = [Point 2 4 2, Point 89 3 78, Point 32 43 8]

constructLine :: Polyline -> Polyline
constructLine line = addPoints points line

app :: App 
app = do
    draw . constructLine $ line
```

Then the `app` written by the user is called in an infinite loop in the main.

The polyline is constructed like this:

```
data Polyline = Polyline { points :: [Point], vbo :: Vbo }

newPolyline :: Polyline
newPolyline = Polyline { points = [], vbo = newVbo }
```

`newVbo` creates a new vertex array using `glGenVertexArrays` from `Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.Raw`. My problem is that a new vertex array is generated at each iteration of the main loop.
How can I make my `Polyline` to be represented by a unique vertex array?

Comment: Assuming `Vbo`s are allocated in `IO`, you will need to `unsafePerformIO` so you can generate the `Vbo` "when" the pure data structure is created.  You will have to make sure that the creation call is not actually made until the graphics stuff is initialized; laziness may just handle this for you.

Comment: Hi @luqui, I read things about `unsafePerformIO` but I'm not sure how to use it. Can you be more specific?